# Spring boot 2 migration from Spring boot 1.5 issue with entityManagerPackages

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have following code in `PersistanceConfig.class` that works fine in SpringBoot 1.5:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {
        "somePackagesName.repository",
        "somePackagesName2.repository",
        "somePackagesName3.repository"
})
class PersistanceConfig extends MultitenancyConfiguration {

@Override
protected Class<?>[] entityManagerPackages() {
    return ImmutableList.of(
            Jsr310JpaConverters.class,
            CalculationDtoJpaConverter.class,
            CommonModel.class,
            Model.class,
            somePackagesName.Model.class,
            somePackagesName.model.Model.class)
            .toArray(new Class[]{});
}
}
```

When running the same way (i used to on Tomcat 8.5)  - now I get following error:

```
18-Oct-2018 13:18:51.798 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/policyManagement]]
(...)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource 
[somePackagesName/PersistanceConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'entityManagerFactory' parameter 3;
 nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
 Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' defined in class path resource 
 [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: 
 Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' parameter 0; 
 nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
 Error creating bean with name 'jpaVendorAdapter' defined in class path resource 
 [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: 
 Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
 Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter]: Factory method 'jpaVendorAdapter' threw exception; 
 nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: jdbcUrl is required with driverClassName.
(...)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' 
defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:
 Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' parameter 0; 
 nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
 Error creating bean with name 'jpaVendorAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: 
 Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
 Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter]: Factory method 'jpaVendorAdapter' 
 threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: jdbcUrl is required with driverClassName.
(...)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaVendorAdapter' 
defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: 
Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate 
[org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter]: Factory method 'jpaVendorAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: jdbcUrl is required with driverClassName.
(...)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter]:
 Factory method 'jpaVendorAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: jdbcUrl is required with driverClassName.
(...)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: jdbcUrl is required with driverClassName.
(...)
```

How can i change this code so it will work in SpringBoot 2.x ?

Here's class that uses `entityManagerPackages`:

```
public abstract class MultitenancyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "primary.datasource")
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "secondary.datasource")
    public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "default.datasource")
    public DataSource defaultDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource,
                                                                       MultiTenantConnectionProvider multiTenantConnectionProvider,
                                                                       CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver currentTenantIdentifierResolver,
                                                                       EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT, MultiTenancyStrategy.DATABASE);
        props.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT_CONNECTION_PROVIDER, multiTenantConnectionProvider);
        props.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT_IDENTIFIER_RESOLVER, currentTenantIdentifierResolver);

        return builder
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .properties(props)
                .packages(entityManagerPackages())
                .build();
    }

    protected abstract Class<?>[] entityManagerPackages();

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean myFilter(AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        Filter tenantFilter = new MultiTenantFilter();
        beanFactory.autowireBean(tenantFilter);
        registration.setFilter(tenantFilter);
        registration.addUrlPatterns("/*");
        return registration;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a duplicate. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49141541/1384297) is particularly relevant.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson awesome - thanks - did not find that before